# ImageButton Scaling issue within ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, imagebutton

Just putting it out there I rarely work with .xml so I am sorry for the basic question. I have looked around for other solutions but none really seem to be helping my issue.

So I am adding an ImageButton to my login screen, and the actual image is too large. Here is what the image looks like when I place it in and make no adjustments.

[image]

The Login button is too big, I want it to fit the size of the login button in the background. So I try to scale it using the resize view handlers, and I also have adjusted `android:layout_width=…` and the height as well. But when I do that the image does not get resized, just the area it is placed in get's resized. This is what happens

[image]

As you can see, it just kind of deletes some parts of the image and adjusts the area the image is in. How can I adjust the actual size of the IMAGE part of the button? This is what I have done in .xml

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/signinButtonLogin"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:background="null"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/loginbutton"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="13dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="447dp" />
```

Sorry if this is a basic question, I am just starting to learn my way around .xml

Comment: This ImageButton tag of .xml file is correct. If you have no any problem then you should use ImageView instead of ImageButton.

Comment: @user7832102 can I use ImageView as a button?